# how to design feed-forward controller, when the transfer function is not realizable

Tags: control-theory

Let's say i have the following dynamics 
$$G_d= \frac{e^{-3s}}{1+s}$$
$$G_p=\frac{e^{-4s}}{(2+s)(3+s)}$$

now on dynamic analysis we get $$G_{ff}=-\frac{G_d}{G_p}$$
we can see $G_{ff}$ is physically not realizable. what i want to do is design a controller that can effectively work if not completely. so this is what
we have $$G_{ff}=e^{s}*\frac{s^2+5s+6}{1+s}$$
i converted this to 
$$G_{ff}=(1+s+\frac{s^2}{2})*\frac{(s^2+5s+6)}{(1+s)*(1+\lambda*s)^3}$$
so basically I expanded exponential part into a taylor series, and i divided the whole function by $(1+\lambda*s)^3$ in order to get a physically realizable function, and i have taken $\lambda$ to be very small, $\lambda=.0001$. Unfortunately the response on simulink to this system is showing huge oscillations and the controller is not working. What can i do to improve this model and am i going in the right direction.

Comment: Why do you want to "model" a noncausal system? Also you also might want to look into [Padé approximants](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PadeApproximant.html).

Comment: Smith Predictor might work for you.

Comment: What is the bandwidth of your controller? And can you show how you combined the feedforward with the feedback?

Comment: I have not included feedback in my system. I wanted to test how feedback works with non casual system. As far as bandwith is concerned i dont quite understand that.